# "I'm waiting you" or I'm waiting FOR / TO you"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the correct way to say someone about your waiting?

> "I'm waiting you"
>
> I'm waiting **for** you"?
>
> I'm waiting **to** you"?

I am not sure if I should use prepositionals, and if I should which of them is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wait" almost always takes "for" for its object, so "I'm waiting for you".

It can also take "until" with a finite clause: "I'm waiting until you come".

You occasionally hear "waiting on" but (apart from its use to mean "attend to people eating") that is dialect or technical.

Answer (score 2):

I find these questions are always much easier to answer yourself if you complete the phrase out into a full sentence.

What should "you" being doing for your wait to be over. Should "you" becoming over here or stopping eating.

> I'm waiting {} you to stop watching telly and go to bed.
>   I'm waiting
>   {} you to get ready so we can go out.
>   I'm waiting {} you to  clean
>   your teeth.
>   I'm waiting {} you stop messing around then we can carry on

One of these example questions is different to the others and may require you to have read Colin's answer first.

p.s. yes I do spend a lot of time waiting for my children.